# XML tag meaning

Tags: c#, xml

I have a part of xml file

```
<Text>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
&lt;ObjectFilter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
  &lt;FilterConditions&gt;
    &lt;FilterCondition&gt;
      &lt;PropertyFilters&gt;
        &lt;PropertyFilter&gt;
          &lt;PropertyName&gt;Message&lt;/PropertyName&gt;
          &lt;FilterValue xsi:type="xsd:string"&gt;PPM exceeds tolerance&lt;/FilterValue&gt;
          &lt;FilterType&gt;strExpr&lt;/FilterType&gt;
          &lt;Operator&gt;eq&lt;/Operator&gt;
          &lt;CaseSensitive&gt;true&lt;/CaseSensitive&gt;
          &lt;Recursive&gt;false&lt;/Recursive&gt;
        &lt;/PropertyFilter&gt;
      &lt;/PropertyFilters&gt;
      &lt;Enabled&gt;true&lt;/Enabled&gt;
      &lt;ObjectTypeName&gt;Spo.DataModel.UnixLogMessage&lt;/ObjectTypeName&gt;
      &lt;ObjectClassGR&gt;
        &lt;Guid&gt;00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&lt;/Guid&gt;
      &lt;/ObjectClassGR&gt;
```

Here what is node Recursive meant,,it actually like this `<Recursive>false</Recursive>`

but how come it like   &lt ;Recursive>false&lt ;/Recursive >
Can any one help me about this

Comment: That can mean absolutely anything. What does this XML file actually represent? I could build an XML file with `<Recursive>Chicken</Recursive>` and only I would know what it means. What your particular tag represents depends entirely on the application.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple. I think the gist of the question was "Why do my tags look like &lt instead of the less-than sign?" and not "What does 'Recursive' mean in my XML file?" A poorly worded question, agreed.

Comment: Hmm. Good point. peter asks both "what is node Recursive meant?" and "how come it like &lt;...". Peter, you may want to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you *getting* this XML file? From a webpage?

It seems that the way you are getting the text file is translating it as an HTML document and thus turning your '<' into &lt and your '>' into &gt

You need to ensure that the page is not interpreted as HTML. You could just copy-paste everything into Notepad first for a simple solution.